# Why does checking the ASCII code of "Del" button returns 83?

Tags: c, ascii

Pressing `Del` is dealt with as it is an extended key, it returns ASCII code `-32` then `83`, while pressing `Ctrl + back` returns the expected `127`: *the actual ASCII of `Del` button*.

Do you know any explanation for this?

```c
char x;
x = getch();
if(x == -32 || x == 0){
x = getch();
    printf("The key you pressed is an Extended Key, with ASCII code: %d\n", x);
}else{
    printf("The key you pressed is a Normal Key, with ASCII code: %d\n", x);
}
```

Comment: If you read the manual page [getch](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getc) it returns an `int` not a character

Comment: -32 = 0xE0, 83 is the scan code.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170#remarks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Del key on a standard keyboard does not generate a "Delete" ASCII code: code 127 in the ASCII table isn't meant to do what the Del key does on a computer, it was designed for electric typewriters.

The Del key is a "special key" in a similar vein as the arrow keys, so when you submit it to `getch()` it will read out it's scan code.

Comment: More specifically, the DEL code in ASCII was meant to punch all the holes in a paper tape punch so that any ASCII code rendered there would be obliterated.